# Is there a representation with logical operators that returns the same result for ternary operator?

Tags: c#, logical-operators, conditional-operator

I am curious about if a logical representation exists for ternary operator that gives the same result for each condition combination. I tried below but it doesn't cover all situations. Is there a correct representation for this problem?

```
Ternary Condition : a ? b : c
Logical Version : (a && b) || c
```

Logical version fails in one condition compared to ternary results when the conditions below are given:

```
(true  && true)  || true  = true 
(true  && true)  || false = true 
(true  && false) || true  = true //must be false
(true  && false) || false = false 
(false && true)  || true  = true 
(false && true)  || false = false
(false && false) || true  = true
(false && false) || false = false
```

Comment: Why must it be false? `(true && false) || true`  is  `(false) || true`  =  `true`

Comment: Because we expect it to give the same ternary condition result which is 'true ? false : true = false'

Comment: Oh I see now :)

Comment: The ternary operator is like a short `if`. `b` and `c` don't have to be boolean values. `b` is the return value if expression `a` returns `true` and `c` if `a` returns false. So the logical version doesn't make sense. Please provide further information on what you want to achieve with this logic.

Comment: @ErikT. what he asks is a logical equivalent for a ternary operation where b and c are also booleans.

Comment: `(a & b) | (!a & c)` is a direct translation and I don't think you can make it simpler than that.

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about pre-evaluated boolean variables or constants, a logical equivalent to the ternary operator can be written like Lee commented

```
(a && b) || (!a && c)
```

Or alternatively as

```
(!a || b) && (a || c)
```

However, since this question is flagged as C#, I think it's important to discuss the case of `a`, `b` or `c` actually being boolean expressions with side effects (like a function call or a property getter with backing logic)

So lets compare the approaches with regard to, how often `a`, `b` and `c` are evaluated:

Case 1: the ternary operator `a ? b : c`, `a` is evaluated exactly once, and depending on `a`, `b` or `c` is evaluated once.

Case 2: `(a && b) || (!a && c)` The number of evaluations of `a` for `a=1` depend on the value of `b`. Note that `#a` is the number of evaluations for `a` expression.

```
a   b   c   #a  #b  #c

0   0   0   2   0   1
0   0   1   2   0   1
0   1   0   2   0   1
0   1   1   2   0   1
1   0   0   2   1   0
1   0   1   2   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   0
```

Case 3: `(!a || b) && (a || c)` again, the number of evaluations of `a` for `a=1` depend on `b`, but in reverse, compared to case 2

```
a   b   c   #a  #b  #c

0   0   0   2   0   1
0   0   1   2   0   1
0   1   0   2   0   1
0   1   1   2   0   1
1   0   0   1   1   0
1   0   1   1   1   0
1   1   0   2   1   0
1   1   1   2   1   0
```

I don't consider the expression evaluation side effect, where the evaluation of `a` changes the value of subsequent evaluations, since it would probably be off topic.